# Jquery - optgroup hide() does not refresh the dropdown until clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide an `optgroup` in a dropdown based on the value selected from a radio button. It all works fine except the dropdown does not get refreshed *immediately* (it may already have a preselected value from earlier, irrespective of the `optgroup` it falls in).

```
$('input[id*="school_type"]').on("change",function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var selectedVal=($(this).next().text()); 
          $("#id_school_sub_type > optgroup").hide(); 
          $('#id_school_sub_type > optgroup[label="'+selectedVal+'"]').show();
        }
    });
```

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anupamjain/twmLaL09/6/)**

The optgroup is hidden or shown only when the user clicks on the subsequent dropdown. Is it possible to "refresh" it immediately?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @maxshuty [here](https://jsfiddle.net/anupamjain/twmLaL09/2/) it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove selection of that item before hide:**

```
$('input[id*="school_type"]').on("change",function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var selectedVal=($(this).next().text()); // using next() so we can get the verbose value from the <span> next to <input>
      $("#id_school_sub_type").val('');
      $("#id_school_sub_type > optgroup").hide(); 
      $('#id_school_sub_type > optgroup[label="'+selectedVal+'"]').show();
    }
});
```

Add following line if want to made selection too:

```
$("#id_school_sub_type").val($('#id_school_sub_type optgroup[label="'+selectedVal+'"] option:first').val());
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twmLaL09/8/)

Comment: Is it possible to 'keep' the selection if it does apply to the pre-selected sub-category? This radio button is not mandatory and the sub category could have been pre- selected without selecting anything in the radio button. I dont want to lose that when the user selects a category in the radio that does map to one of the previously selected subcategories.

Comment: Yes, I've added a statement above for keep selection

Comment: But that statement will always select the first option in the drop down? Here's an example of what I mean: Suppose Category 1-B is already selected, and nothing in the radio buttons is selected. If the user then selects Category 1 in the radio button, then we'll lose the Category 1-B that was selected earlier. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Anupam get the current selection index, before the change, and re-apply it after the change.

Comment: @Stavm, sure, I was thinking to do that but was wondering if there's another built-in way of doing it. Perhaps not. Will do that then - thanks both!

Comment: Govind and @Stavm: This is what I ended up doing:
`if ($('#id_school_sub_type option:selected').parent().attr('label') != selectedVal) {
            $("#id_org_sub_type").val('');
          }`